# Remote sql server usage?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms

I've a user account on a development SQL express on a remote server. This account has all privileges granted to it but when I use SQL express remotely then I'm not able to make changes to tables. If I log into the virtual machine and sign in with same user I can make changes.

It says I'm not database owner or system administrator. I think I may need to use ownership chaining or somehow designate my user account as administrator?

Thanks.

This is what I'm seeing:

http://fogcreek.com/FogBugz/kb/errors/SysAdminRole.html

I'm using SQL Server Authentication but I'm not the owner but have 'grant' all rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! This explains how I can add my user to the appropriate role and that fixes the problem.

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-1061781.html?tag=mantle_skin